# Understanding xcolor color mixing model

Tags: color

I fail to understand the color mixing of `xcolor`.

I want to have a lighter and a darker version of a color defined as

```
\definecolor{BlueLUH}{cmyk}{1.0,0.7,0,0}
```

My approach of lighter and darker is this one

```
\colorlet{LightBlue}{BlueLUH!20!white}
\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black!20}
```

which according to the docs is replaced internally to

```
\colorlet{LightBlue}{BlueLUH!20!white!white}
\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black!20!white}
```

Now I wonder what is actually calulated, bcause I get the same for Light and Dark, as can be seen in the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think `white` is only taken as default color if there is no second color, so: `BlueLUH!20` is taken as `BlueLUH!20!white`, while `BlueLUH!20!white` will stay as it is and not taken as `BlueLUH!20!white!white`. But I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: that would make sence. Nevertheless how is it calulated? Blue*0.8 + black*0.2 + 1.0*white or blue*1.0+black*0.8+white*0.2 or even different?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That are different colors, but cannot be seen! 20% of black is less than light gray! Compare it with a 40% of black!  The values for the cmyk color can easily be seen in the pdf output when using `\pdfcompresslevel=0`.

The colors are calculated as:

[image]

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

\definecolor{BlueLUH}{cmyk}{1.0,0.7,0,0}
\colorlet{LightBlue}{BlueLUH!20!white}
\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black!20}
%\colorlet{LightBlue}{BlueLUH!20!white!white}
%\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black!20!white}

\begin{document} 

\color{BlueLUH}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color{LightBlue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color{DarkBlue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\color[cmyk]{1, 0.7, 0, 0}\rule{1cm}{1cm} 
\color[cmyk]{0.2, 0.14, 0, 0}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color[cmyk]{0.16, 0.112, 0, 0.04}\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black!40}
\color{BlueLUH}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color{LightBlue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color{DarkBlue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is correct that they are not equal, but they are so close that the eye can not distinguish between them. Unfortunately this does not tell me how to get darker colors using colormixing with xcolor.

Comment: from which document are these formulas? i can not find them within the xcolor package. I understand how red!75 is calculated with eqn (1), but the calculation of red!75!blue!100 does not seems to be relatd to eqn (1). At least something in the calculation was left out, since eqn (1) does not mention how more than one color is combined.

Comment: (1) is a loop, as already mentioned ... and it is _my_ text from _my_ book ... :-)

Comment: What is the unit vector `e`? If we do the the maths based on the cited paragraph, then `e = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25)` which is doesn't have norm 1.

Answer (score 11):

For darker color try `\colorlet{DarkBlue}{BlueLUH!80!black}` instead.
This way it will be `Blue*0.8 + black*0.2`.

If you add second number then *third* color (i.e. white) will be added, and you don't need that.
As I understand it, `BlueLUH!80!black!30` would be `(Blue*0.8 + black*0.2)*0.3 + white*0.7`

Please see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Examples