# pdflatex - transparent package seems not to work

Tags: pdftex, transparency

I am trying to use the 'transparent' package, as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45596/how-to-specify-transparent-colors#45601):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
  \colorbox{red}{%
    Black text in a red box %
    \transparent{1.0}%
    \colorbox{blue}{%
      and now a blue box is added%
    }
  }

  \colorbox{red}{%
    Black text in a red box %
    \transparent{0.5}%
    \colorbox{blue}{%
      and now a transparent blue box is added%
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

But it seems not to work with current TeX or **pdflatex.** Is there an approach that works with **pdflatex**?

[image]

---

**Edit**: After compiling a few times (from TeXMaker), suddenly I can see the tranparency, although I did not change the .tex file nor the pdflatex command. Is this a bug?

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a feature: `Package transparent Warning: Rerun to get transparencies right.` ;-) You have to run (at least) twice.

Comment: Oh alright. At best confusing...

Comment: Here, at my end, compiling it twice was enough.

Comment: I'm sure I ran it at least four times before the change was effective, but well, it works now

Comment: @EmitTaste: A small side note: The chosen colours are awful ;-)

Comment: That's just a reference example. In my actual case I am overlaying a beautifully shot photo with a smooth white with a hint of tranceparents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `transparent` manual:

> 2.3 Transparency The setting for the different transparency values must be added to the page resources. In the first run the values are
>   recorded in the .aux file. In the second run the values are set and
>   transparency is available.

This means, that the first run writes information to the `.aux` and the second run grabs those values and sets the whole feature up.

→ **Compile twice**

[image]