# Does it make sense to convert lightgray into cmyk for more legible printing results? Does this necessitate choosing a (different and) darker colour?

Tags: color, pdf, printing

In my document I'm using the colour `lightgray` which looks nice on screen, but is barely decipherable when printed (with a BW-laser-printer). Using the `xcolor` pkg:

- Would it make sense to try and convert `lightgray` with `\convertcolorspec` to a `cmyk` equivalent for more legible *printing* results?
- Would this necessitate choosing a *darker* colour, or could a `cmyk` 1:1 equiv. of `lightgray` be chosen that looks exactly like the original `lightgray` on *screen* ?
- If so, how to code it?

A pretty plain MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[6]

{\textcolor{lightgray} {\lipsum[3]}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Some more or less random snippets from the xcolor manual %%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \extractcolorspec{lightgray}\tmpa
% \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmpa{cmyk}\tmpb
% \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmpa{RGB}\tmpc

% {\textcolor{\extractcolorspec{lightgray}{\tmpa\expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmpa{cmyk}\tmpb}}{\lipsum[2]}}

% \convertcolorspec

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors via svgnames option

% LightSlateGray
% LightSlateGrey

% Silver
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% - enhanced color deﬁnition syntax to allow for target-model speciﬁc color parameters, e.g., \definecolor {red}{rgb/cmyk}{1,0,0/0,1,1,0}, facilitating the usage of tailor-made colors both for displays and printers; 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

---

See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973/27721).

Comment: @Herbert [possibly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13081/27721) `\pdfcompresslevel=0` [could help...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34913/27721) ?

Comment: Excellent article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variations_of_gray

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a graphic design issue rather than a technical one.

Comment: I suspect this would be better covered, probably without the 'TeX detail', on the GraphicsDesign site.